# Установка cookie на поддомены localhost посредством javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Устанавливаю cookie с помощью конструкции

```
document.cookie = 'list=' + list + '; expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + '; path=/';
```

Код работает, cookie устанавливается. Пытаюсь добавить возможность установки на поддомены (sub.localhost) с помощью строки ниже. Код работает, но не устанавливает на **указанный** домен, в данном случае localhost. Т.е. если я устанавливаю cookie с домена test.localhost, то test.localhost (а не ожидаемый localhost) и указывается в качестве узла:

```
document.cookie = 'list=' + list + '; expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + '; path=/; ' + '".localhost"' ;
```

Код ниже вообще не работает, cookie не устанавливается:

```
document.cookie = 'list=' + list + '; expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + '; path=/; ' + 'domain=.localhost' ;
```

В Chrome и Firefox поведение одинаковое. Прошу подсказать, что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie ;domain=domain (пример: 'example.com' или 'subdomain.example.com'). Если не указан, по умолчанию используется домен запрошенной страницы (не включая суб домен). Вопреки предыдущим спецификациям, **точка(и) в начале доменного имени игнорируются**. **Если домен указан, все субдомени всегда включаются**.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо за ответ, про точку не знал. Но ничего не изменилось, cookie не устанавливается с помощью _document.cookie = 'list=' + list + '; expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + '; path=/; ' + 'domain=localhost' ;_. Взятие в кавычки domain="localhost" ни на что не повлияло.

Comment: Видимо причина в этом http://stackoverflow.com/a/8912321/5441700

Comment: @Visman, спасибо большое, так и есть, на реальном домене все заработало. Запись такая: _document.cookie = 'list=' + list + '; expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + '; path=/; ' + 'domain=mydomain.com' ;_ Напишите то, что вы нашли в качестве _ответа на вопрос_, он может еще кому-нибудь помочь.