# PHP: установить COOKIE для поддомена

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, разобраться почему не устанавливаются COOKIE для поддоменов сайта.

Мне необходимо запустить скрипт на `http://localhost`, чтобы он установил параметры для поддомена `http://test1.localhost`

На главном домене в скрипте пишу:

```
setcookie ("param", 'test1', time()+7*24*60*60, "/", ".localhost");
```

Запускаю, с учетом, что перед `localhost` стоит точка, значит параметры `param=test1` должны передаваться на любой поддомен.

После этого смотрю на поддомене массив `$_COOKIE`, но там ничего нет.

Я также не могу явно установить  cookie для поддомена:

```
  setcookie ("param", 'test1', time()+7*24*60*60, "/", "test1.localhost");
```

Однако, для самого домена cookie устанавливаются(указав последним аргументов `"localhost"`)

Если на главном поддомене обернуть `setcookie` в print_r(), то результатом будет `1`, значит функция выполняется успешно.

Но в чем проблема? Браузер chrome, cookie включены.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: цитата из мануала: _Для того, чтобы сделать cookie доступными для всего домена (включая поддомены), нужно просто указать имя домена (т.е. 'example.com')._ Ваш домен _localhost_ ? Попробуйте его и указать _(без точки)_

Comment: @Эдуард, Если указать "localhost" без точки, то устанавливаются только для localhost-a, а в поддоменах пустота.

Comment: Возможно примеры с localhost могут некорректно работать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/667639/186083 В комментариях пояснение по localhost.

Comment: "test1.localhost" - это тоже домен второго уровня, как и "example.com". Так что дело не в уровне домена, а именно в "localhost". Просто в том примере на который дал ссылку Visman кто то пытался задать куки для домена первого уровня ".localhost" поэтому тот ответ немного про другое.

Comment: @Hipster, тут как раз проблема в домене верхнего уровня, так как localhost это домен верхнего уровня, как и ru.

Comment: @Visman Почему тогда "example.com" работает корректно, а  "test1.localhost" нет?

Comment: @Hipster, вы проверяли куку установленную на `test1.localhost` на доступность в `test2.test1.localhost`?

Comment: @Visman Автор пишет что у него не получилось.

Comment: @Hipster, автор в вопросе речь ведет о `localhost`, в том числе пытается поставить находясь на  `localhost` куки в `test1.localhost`.

Answer (score -1):

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time() + 3600, "/", "www.example.com");
```

Задание поддомена (например 'www.example.com') сделает cookie доступными в нем и во всех его поддоменах (например w2.www.example.com).

Comment: а у ТС разве не то же самое в посту с вопросом написано? _setcookie ("param", 'test1', time()+7*24*60*60, "/", "test1.localhost");_ -- где _test1_ это поддомен, а _localhost_ домен.

Comment: Возможно примеры с localhost могут некорректно работать.